# GIS QUERY on point and buffer

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a point table and the buffer geometry is created around the point.

I have defined the if the point is within the buffer_distance then its value is =1
and if it is outside the buffer its value is =0, and when it is on buffer_polygon then =2.

Now when ever i change the location of point then it should check the following conditions and the flag value should change according to the location of point new position.

I am changing the position of the point in QGIS.

My table structure is like this:-

```
GID(PK) Flag(INT)   Buffer_Distance THE_Geom    Buffer_GEOM
1   1   100 point(X,Y Location) Buffer Created around the Point 
2   2   200 point(X,Y Location) Buffer Created around the Point 
3   2   200 point(X,Y Location) Buffer Created around the Point 
4   3   300 point(X,Y Location) Buffer Created around the Point 
5   3   300 point(X,Y Location) Buffer Created around the Point 
6   1   100 point(X,Y Location) Buffer Created around the Point
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear as to which point(s) are buffered and which ones might be moved in QGis but I think you need to define a trigger on your point table to run the query whenever a point is changed.

See if http://twiav-tt.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/postgis-trigger-function-retrieve.html helps? Or this answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962120/need-help-writing-a-postgresql-trigger-function)?

Answer (score 1):

Read about PostgreSQL [Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html). Real world [example](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Brief_Real-world_Trigger_Example). You probably need after update or insert trigger.

Answer (score -1):

sir me have a point Table , in which the point geometry and the buffer geometry is created now if i move the point location in quantum gis then the values of the point should change.

Comment: Please add this as a comment