# updatation query along a point

Tags: qgis, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIS QUERY on point and buffer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42344/gis-query-on-point-and-buffer)

All,

I have a PostGIS/Postgresql DB that has one table in it. One with point geometries and the other that represents buffer as polygons. i would like to updted the flag field in the same table when ever mine point location geometry is changed. if the point is outside the buffer polygon then its value should be 0, or flag value should be 1 when it is inside the buffer polygon.

mine table is as follows

gid flag    point(geom)         polygon(geom)

1   2   the point Geometry  the polygon Geometry
2   1   the point Geometry  the polygon Geometry
3   2   the point Geometry  the polygon Geometry
4   1   the point Geometry  the polygon Geometry

manish